# Merging code changes from two repositories in git

Tags: git, git-merge

My code is in my local repo and also on my bitbucket remote.

```
mine$ git remote -v
origin  git@bitbucket.org:example/example.git (fetch)
origin  git@bitbucket.org:example/example.git (push)
```

A supplier had a copy of the code and made changes. They used their own local git remote to which I have not access. I have now received their code as a zip. It is setup with its own git remote.

```
theirs$ git remote -v
origin  //someComputer/otherExample.git (fetch)
origin  //someComputer/otherExample.git (push)
```

How should I merge their changes in my repo?

Their zip also contains uncommitted changes, must I first commit them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first add their repository as a new remote,

```
git remote add supplier_remote /home/user/supplier_repo
```

Then checkout your branch, and merge their relevant branch, for example, the master branch,

```
git checkout master
git pull supplier_remote master
```

Committing their uncommitted changes is up to you, if you want them you can go ahead and commit, if not, only committed changes will be merged.

Comment: You'll have to `fetch` from `supplier_remote` before you can merge.

Comment: You could also overwrite with their changes using git merge -X supplier_remote/master